# Dashboard/Status Board Software For PC

Tags: windows, dashboard

Looking for something along the lines of [Status Board 2](https://panic.com/statusboard/) which is only for iPad, but I want this to run on a PC instead.  Looking for something that we can manipulate and put different widgets on, such as weather, text, date and time, etc.  It's just going to sit in our office, show us the weather, and some information like job bidding(we're a construction company), and job status, and such.

Edit:  Can be for Windows 7 or 10, we have machines running both.  No real price point in mind, mostly just looking at the best solution, depending on the abilities of the software, price might not be as big of a factor.

Comment: Which Windows version? Price?

Comment: @New-To-IT Do you need a tool that also helps you to generate content? Or just something with the ability to gather and display information/data that is already accessible (e.g. through [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS))?

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'd like an explanation as to how I can make my question better?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own with [Windows App Studio](http://appstudio.windows.com/en-us) . I don't have any experience with it (and it says "beta" there) but it looks like what you are looking for.